# How do I send a Google API POST request using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, httprequest, google-cloud-vision

I have never used Jmeter before. I have been trying to use Jmeter to send an HTTP request to Google Vision API - but it's returning a FORBIDDEN (403) error. My request as well as required response is in JSON format.
I have attached below the:
a) HTTP Request
b) Response Error

Other than this, in HTTP Header Manager I have set:
Content-Type: application/json

What is wrong with the attached request?
[Request image..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNz2y.png) 
[Response error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AapNj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Authenticating to the Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth) article you might require to provide OAuth token, it can be done via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) like:

- Name: `Authorization`
- Value: `Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for more details on interacting with OAuth-protected web applications in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thanks, that was indeed required. I generated and added my access token. But the 403 error remains as it is. Response: 
{  
  "error": {  
    "code": 403,  
    "message": "SSL is required to perform this operation.",  
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"  
  }  
}

Comment: Okay it worked. It was a simple matter of using HTTPS instead of HTTP. *feels stupid*